# How to open some child links in new tab in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a page built with React (NextJS) and I am pulling some markup string content from Wordpress and inserting it into my `JSX`, like so:

```
...
<div className="wrapper">
  <p
     className="text-content"
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }}
  ></p>
</div>
...
```

Now, the markup possibly contains links and I want to open all those links on new tab. So I tried:

```
...
<div className="wrapper">
  <base target="_blank" />
  <p
     className="text-content"
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }}
  ></p>
</div>
...
```

and all links in the markup are opened on new tab so, great. But the problem is that all other links in the page including those outside the `div.wrapper` element are opened in new tabs (since `<base />` is scoped to the entire page) and I'll like to prevent this.

Since I can't use multiple `<base />` on the same page, the other option I'm aware of is to loop through anchor tags of interest with `document.querySelector(".wrapper a")` and add the `target` attribute to all of them but, in React it's an anti-pattern to modify the DOM directly.

So I'm not sure how best to proceed. What do I do?

Comment: can you edit the _post.content.rendered_ before adding to the dom ?

Comment: Yes I can @ishansrivastava

Comment: So before adding _post.content.rendered_ to the dom, editing all its anchor tags to open the link in a new tab.
You can do that using regex, but I would not suggest that.
I'd suggest you can make a fake dom, with the _post.content.rendered_ , and then proceed with dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DOMParser API to achieve that.

Here's a little snippet

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlText = `<div><a href="#some-url">Url link</a></div>`;

let content = parser.parseFromString(htmlText, "text/html");
const anchors = content.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.from(anchors).forEach(a => { 
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
})


console.log(content.body.innerHTML); // Here it is your new string
```

The code may need to be improved a bit, I've just typed this out of MDN example and I didn't have time to test it. Does this work?

Comment: yep - like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all base element should only be inserted in html head element, and not inside the body html element, you could do that imperatively or using the [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) library - if you still need to use it.

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is in itself an imperative pice of code, but sometimes its the only possible solutions for a certain use cases, now regarding the links you could either do it using imperative code in a `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`, or you code use [react-html-parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser#readme) which will enable you to modify dom elements in a more declarative fashion   - i say in a more declarative fashion because while its a react component in practice its still more imperative than its declarative in nature, but still better than custom code running in `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`